# New and delete operators without effect on the contents of a Deque of pointers to this class

Tags: c++, new-operator, deque, delete-operator

I have a problem that I have been tackling since the last two days, but as a rather inexperienced programmer it is normal I assume. My question may have an easy solution, but I couldn't find a quick reference, so decided to ask it to others.

In one thread of an application, I create with `new`, a pointer to a user defined class. Immediately after it, I push that new created pointer into a `deque` of pointers to this user defined class, with `push_back()` method.

This deque under concern had been passed to this thread from the main function of the application, where the contents of this user-defined class are processed in the main loop. Thus, when a new pointer enters into the deque, it is taken in main thread, and used.

My problem is that I need to make sure that the memory allocated to the contents of this class should be deallocated after use, because they store very large image arrays. Otherwise, the program crashes. For this, I have used `delete` immediately after the `push_back()` call in the thread, assuming that the memory is eventually free, but is stored only in the `deque`. However, apparently, the contents of the address pointed by the pointer in `deque` is also deleted. This is not what I desire.

Is there a way to decouple both, maybe without introducing pointers? I think `new` and `delete` are only valid in pointers. More precisely, is there a way to pass the contents of this class to the `deque` and then delete it, without affecting what is in the `deque`?

Comment: Look for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Probably better to have a `deque` of `std::shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: I used boost::shared_ptr and a deque to the shared pointers, which seems to have solved my problem. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using raw pointers, consider using [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html):

> Boost.Pointer Container provides containers for holding heap-allocated
>   objects in an exception-safe manner and with minimal overhead. The aim
>   of the library is in particular to make OO programming easier in C++
>   by establishing a standard set of classes, methods and designs for
>   dealing with OO specific problems

But this is a valid choice if:

> ```
> the stored objects are not shared, but owned exclusively, or
>
> the overhead implied by smart pointers is inappropriate
> ```

Otherwise, if your image file pointers are shared, consider using `std::shared_ptr` as pointed out in the comments.

If Boost Pointer Container fits your needs, you can use [boost::ptr_deque](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_deque.html)

Comment: Thank you indeed for this. I used the boost library's shared pointer. I don't delete anymore the shared pointer. However, in a continuous process, there is still some memory leak. Because when I check the memory usage of the PC during the application run, it linearly increases and again makes the application crash. One question: The objects that I am pointing with shared pointer also contain pointers to other objects, created with new. Do I need to apply the shared pointer everywhere, throughout the application, or is my problem irrelevant of this?

Comment: @user2365979 can you post your code and end the error you get before the crash? is it a signal (SIGSEV)?